# WPF DataGrid eats all the exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, exception

I have a WPF application which opens a database table, populates a DataTable with the contents of a table in the database, and then uses a System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid to provide a view of that. Updating the database occurs in response to user input in the DataGrid.

The table in the database used for this demo does not have a primary key, so while inserts into the database work fine, attempting to update an existing value will throw an exception. This is expected, I know how to fix this, and that is not the problem. The problem is that the exception that gets thrown when calling Update on the DataAdapter is silently eaten. I need this exception to propogate up the stack to a location where it can be sensibly handled. This code is just a demo, in my real code the assembly that produces the DataTable (and contains the handler where the exception occurs) is a reusable low level assembly that has no UI dependencies.

Here are my exception catch handlers in App.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        DispatcherUnhandledException += OnCurrent_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnCurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void OnCurrent_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
        DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(args.Exception.Message, "Exception Caught");
        args.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnCurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender,
        UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(args.ExceptionObject.ToString(), "Exception Caught");
    }
}
```

Here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs. I'm using an SqLite database because it's what I have installed on this machine. But I'm pretty sure the database used has nothing to do with this issue and the results would be the same using anything else.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitLocalDatabase();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataTable Table { get; private set; }

    private void InitLocalDatabase()
    {
        string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string databaseName = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "testdb.sqlite");
        string connectionString = "Data Source=" + databaseName + ";";

        if (!File.Exists(databaseName))
        {
            // Create and open database.
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(databaseName);
            _connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
            _connection.Open();

            // Create table in database.
            const string createTable = "create table Table1 (Column1 int, Column2 int)";
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(createTable, _connection))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // Add data to table.
            const string addRow = "insert into Table1 values ({0}, {1})";
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2)
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(
                    string.Format(addRow, i, i + 1), _connection))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
        }

        // Create the DataAdapter and DataTable.
        _dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from Table1", _connection);
        SQLiteCommandBuilder cb = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(_dataAdapter);
        Table = new DataTable();
        _dataAdapter.Fill(Table);
        Table.RowChanged += OnDataTable_RowChanged;
    }

    private void OnDataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Assert(Dispatcher.CheckAccess()); // Verify UI thread.
            _dataAdapter.Update(Table);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Throwing exception");
            throw new Exception("Shit happens"); // This is eaten.
        }
    }

    private void OnButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Throwing exception");
        throw new Exception("Shit happens!!"); // This is not eaten.
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnClosing(args);
        if(_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
            _connection = null;
        }
    }

    private SQLiteConnection _connection;
    private SQLiteDataAdapter _dataAdapter;
}
```

My MainWindow.xaml is simply

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="OnButton_Click">Button 1</Button>
    <DataGrid Height="200" ItemsSource="{local:ThrowBinding Table, ElementName=_this}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Notice I have a Button in there too the click handler of which also throws. That works as expected with the "Exception Caught" MessageBoxs being correctly displayed.

Also notice I'm using a custom Binding subclass with exception filtering disabled. The code for that is as follows.

```cs
public class ThrowBinding : Binding
{
    public ThrowBinding()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public ThrowBinding(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = _exceptionFilter;
        ValidationRules.Add(_validationRule);
    }

    private static object ExceptionFilter(object bindingExpression, Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    private static readonly UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallback _exceptionFilter = ExceptionFilter;
    private static readonly ExceptionValidationRule _validationRule = new ExceptionValidationRule();
}
```

I've built using AnyCpu and x86 configurations and the result is the same, the exception thrown by OnDataTable_RowChanged when attempting to edit an existing value is silently eaten. This is really not good. If some exceptions are going to get silently eaten then that's going to make a mockery of any attempt at robustness.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a bug there and you can't actually catch exceptions you throw from RowChanged event. [Here](http://www.hightechtalks.com/dotnet-framework-ado-net/datatable-rowchanged-event-swallowing-exceptions-163416.html) is their "by design" explanation.
What you can do is either use RowChanging event or try setting [ContinueUpdateOnError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.continueupdateonerror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and afterwards use [GetErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.geterrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check if any of your rows have errors that occurred while updating.

Comment: Thanks, well dug up. About the one thing I didn't Google was the name of the handler itself.

Comment: Unfortunately exceptions thrown from DataTable.RowChanging seem to get eaten too. What's more although you can use ContinueUpdateOnError to set RowError on the failed rows, it seems that the WPF DataGrid doesn't fire any event that occurs after the edit/update in which you could actually check for the RowError. So all in all its a bit of a nightmare and I still don't have a solution. So although your reply was helpful I'm going to untick it as a solution to see if an actual solution turns up.

Comment: I think you can use HasErrors(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.haserrors(v=vs.110).aspx) property to check if any of the rows have errors, and in case HasErrors is true you must go through every row returned by GetErrors to check the errors.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3877412(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But what event gets fired _after_ the update in which you can check the property?